# Command to List Installed and Enabled GNOME Extensions

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I want a command to list all extensions currently installed. Also, a command to list all enabled extensions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your locally installed gnome Shell extensions, i.e., these that are installed for your user only, can be listed with the commmand:

```
ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

You can find out which extensions are enables by querying a dconf setting:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
```

System wide installed gnome-shell extensions are listed with the command

```
ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

Comment: Doesn't gnome-tweaks provide an interface to enable/disable gnome extensions?

Comment: @DKBose, OP is asking for commands.

Comment: I was referring to the last para where you wrote "These extensions can only be disabled ..." which isn't the same as removing using `sudo apt remove`.

Comment: Best to do this at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: @vanadium GNOME extensions can NOT be removed with `sudo apt remove`, as most are not installed by apt, but rather at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: @DKBose You are right indeed. also system wide extensions can be disabled by gnome-tweaks. Editing the post.

Comment: @heynnema System wide extensions such as Ubuntu-dock and Kstatusnotifier are removed like that. Look into Software: you will find a selection of extensions that can be installed systemwide through the package management system.

Comment: @vanadium as I mention... "as most are not installed by apt". So yes, `sudo apt remove` may work in specific cases.

Answer (score 24):

[This command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gnome-extensions.1.html):

```
gnome-extensions list
```

will show all extensions enabled and disabled. To only show those extensions which are enabled use the command:

```
gnome-extensions list --enabled
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that `gnome-extensions` command is available from Gnome 34.