# Which GNOME shell extensions directory takes precedence/priority?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133799/541417), GNOME shell extensions can be found in two directories. Namely,

- `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`
- `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

If I have the same extension (but of different versions) installed into each of these directories, how do I know which extension will actually be used when I log in as a standard user? Or will such a situation cause a conflict to GNOME shell? The assumption here is that this extension is enabled.

E.g.

- `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/extA@gmail.com`
- `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/extA@gmail.com`

Also, as root/sudo this command was executed.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['extA@gmail.com']"
```

Now, when I am logged-in as user, which extensions will I be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many other things (for example `.desktop` launchers for applications), the local directory has the higher priority.

(Now defunct) '*Ubuntu GNOME*' flavour of Ubuntu used to come with a few extensions (e.g. AlternateTab, Applications Menu, Window List etc.) installed system-wide (hence in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory) by default. If there was an update for such an extension and if the user updated it using the [GNOME Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/), it used to create a local copy (in the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory) of the extension with the updated version overriding the older system-wide one.